# Using new google routes api - how can I render (show) route result to a map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, routes, google-routes-api

Using "old" google directions api we had **directionsService** for encapsulating rest query & **directionsRenderer** to show results to the map.

Directions API example for javascript:

```
    // 1. init route config
    let route = {
      origin: {
        ...
      },
      destination: {
        ...
      },
      ...
    }

    // 2. link map to renderer
    this.directionsRenderer.setMap(this.map);

    // 3. make request
    this.directionsService
    .route(direction)
    .then((response) => {
      // 4. render route on map
      this.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
    })
```

As for the **new routes api**: directionsService can be replaced by raw query code, but what about "directionsRenderer"?
How can I apply response['routes'] to the map?

I can't see any examples in official docs, as well as no client library for JS.

Comment: You need to [request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/choose_fields) the [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/traffic_on_polylines) in the response field mask. See also the [Polyline encoding/decoding utilities](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#encoding.decodePath) from the Geometry library.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps JavaScript API does not currently provide a Routes API *service* or a **renderer** to [display routes directly](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DisplayingResults); there doesn't seem to be one yet, so you could [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1244012&template=1733024).

For now, you need to query the Routes API web service endpoints (REST or gRPC) either from JavaScript or through your own servers. A few examples were recently added to the Routes API documentation:

- [Routes request with client-side JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/compute_route_directions#example_routes_request_with_client-side_javascript)
- [Get a route: Node.js](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/compute_route_directions#node.js)
- [Get a route matrix: Client-side JavaScript example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/compute_route_matrix#client-side_javascript_example)

To facilitate querying the Routes API from your server applications, [Routes API client libraries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/client-libraries) are available for [Java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/main/java-maps-routing), [Go](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/maps/routing/apiv2), [Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/tree/main/packages/google-maps-routing), [Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/main/packages/google-maps-routing) and [.Net](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/tree/main/apis/Google.Maps.Routing.V2).

The recommended approach is to build your client-side applications so they call your own servers, let your servers query the Routes API, and secure your servers so that only your applications are allowed to query them (e.g. using [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check)).

When querying the Routes API directly from JavaScript code, which is visible to users, API keys should be **tightly restricted**:

- [**Restrict API keys**](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices) to allow the necessary **HTTP Referers**.
- [Limit API **requests per user**](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage) to prevent unauthorized use and charges.
- Keep JavaScript usage of Routes API in a **separate project** from server-side usage of Routes API, so that lower per-user limits can be applied on the project used (only) in JavaScript applications.
- Make sure that all **other** API keys are **restricted to specific APIs**, so they may not be used on Routes API.

Comment: Thanks for your info, it`s really useful for me for better understanding of new api.

Still concerning to the **rendering** of a route on map, can you advise optimized steps for displaying "complete image" route,
ex: 
1. request api
2. decode polyline
3. set decoded polyline to map
4. create markers for origin/destination
5. create markers for waypoints
... more things todo

Comment: That is no single optimal solution, it depends on what you want to do. For 1. see examples linked above, for 2. use google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath() to decode the polyline and then google.maps.Polyline() to render it, for 3. same as 2. with perhaps a different color, for 4. and 5. see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/